# query CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES

Tags: c++, opencl

I am trying to query and output MAX WORK ITEM SIZES on my laptop. 
The query has a return type `size_t[]` as shown [here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceInfo.html)

However I am still not able to output it. How do I output MAX WORK ITEM SIZES? 
Did I declare the variable correctly?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    vector<cl::Platform> platforms; // available platforms
    vector<cl::Device> devices;     // devices available to a platform
    string outputString;                // string for output
    VECTOR_CLASS<::size_t> maxWorkItem[3];  // for MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES
    unsigned int i, j;                      // counters

        cl::Platform::get(&platforms);

        // for each platform
        for (i = 0; i < platforms.size(); i++)
        {
            vector<cl::Device> devices; // available devices 

            //get all devices available to the platform
            platforms[i].getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, &devices);

            //for each device 
            for (j = 0; j < devices.size(); j++)
            {
                cl_device_type type;
                devices[j].getInfo(CL_DEVICE_TYPE, &type);

                if (type == CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU)
                {
                    platforms[i].getInfo(CL_PLATFORM_NAME, &outputString);
                    cout << "\tName of Platform: " << outputString << std::endl;

                    cout << "\tType: " << "CPU" << endl;


                    //Help here
                    maxWorkItem[0] = devices[j].getInfo<CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES>();
                    cout << "\tMax Work Item Size: " << maxWorkItem[0] << endl;

                    cout << "--------------------------------------------------" << endl;

                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways, depending on the `Device::getInfo()` overload you use. Note that MAX WORK ITEM SIZES gives you the maximum number of work-items that can be specified in **each dimension** of the work-group:

1.

```cpp
// ...
vector<size_t> maxWorkItem;
unsigned int i, j, k;

//...

        //Help here
        maxWorkItem = devices[j].getInfo<CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES>();
        for (k = 0 ; k < maxWorkItem.size(); ++k)
        {
            cout << "\tMax Work Item Size (dim " << k << "): " << maxWorkItem[k] << endl;
        }
        cout << "--------------------------------------------------" << endl;

//...
```

2.

```cpp
// ...
size_t maxWorkItem[3];
unsigned int i, j, k;

//...

        //Help here
        devices[j].getInfo(CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES, &maxWorkItem);
        for (k = 0 ; k < 3; ++k)
        {
            cout << "\tMax Work Item Size (dim " << k << "): " << maxWorkItem[k] << endl;
        }
        cout << "--------------------------------------------------" << endl;

//...
```

Check the [OpenCL C++ bindings documentation](https://github.khronos.org/OpenCL-CLHPP/classcl_1_1_device.html) for more information.